# Page Transition Is not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have  three page in my signle html file. And i am chaning Pages on Button Click Now i am changing page with transition but when page is changed there appears white space between page transition and also give jerk effect i added all javascript helping libraraies applied all approaches but its not working. Hours and Hours attempts are all in vain. and another problem is that when i change my page it seems that onPageChange layout settings of page change again and again. Any body who can help me out in this problem?

Flow is:

1------ Page One (Home Page---First Loaded Page) This page have two buttons and background image

2------ Page Two (this page have some input type images and a button which which goes back to the Home Page)

3------Page Three (This page Also have SOme divs and a button Which goes back to the Home Page)

```
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0.50, user-scalable=no"
name="viewport">



<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>



<body>
    <!-- Start of first page: #one -->
    <div data-role="page" id="one">
       <div id='home' >

    <input type="image"  id='button_1'  src="images/image_1.png"  onclick="first_function();"/>
  <input type="image"  id='button_2' src="images/image_2.png" onclick="second_function();" />


         </div>
    </div><!-- /page one -->


 <!-- Start of second page: #two -->
    <div data-role="page" id="two">



<div id="fullpage">
<img id="player" src="./images/rect.png"
style="margin-left: 65px" />

<input type="image" class="stage"
style="width: 80px; height: 90px; margin-left: 65px;"
onclick="myFunction('1','1');" id="1" value=" " name=""/>


<input type="image" class="stage"
style="width: 80px; height: 90px; margin-left: 30px;"
onclick="myFunction('2','1');" id="2" value=" " name=""/>

<input  type="image" class="stage"
style="width: 80px; height: 90px; margin-left: 50px;"
onclick="myFunction('3','1'); " id="3" value=" " name=""/>



<div id="home-btn">


<input type="image" id="home"
style="position: absolute; width: 90px; height: 90px; margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 210px;"
src="images/home.png"
 value=" " name="home" onClick="home_function();"/>



</div>



</div>

    </div><!-- /page two -->



 <!-- Start of second page: #three -->
    <div data-role="page" id="three">

<div style='display: block; background-image: url(./images/imagee1.jpg);'   >

<button class="stage1"
style="width: 280px; height: 130px; margin-top: 25px; margin-left: 40px; background: transparent;"
onclick="audio('11')" ></button>
<button class="stage1"
style="width: 280px; height: 340px; margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 960px; background: transparent;"
onclick="audio('22')" ></button>

<button id="home" id="home"
style="position: absolute; width: 90px; height: 90px; margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 255px; background: url('./images/home.png');" onClick="home_function();"></button>

<button class="stage1"
style="width: 220px; height: 290px; margin-top: 435px; margin-left: 40px; background: transparent;"
onclick="audio('33')"></button>
<button class="stage1"
style="width: 210px; height: 290px; margin-top: 435px; margin-left: 300px; background: transparent;"
onclick="audio('44')" ></button>
<button class="stage1"
style="width: 240px; height: 290px; margin-top: 435px; margin-left: 550px; background: transparent;"
onclick="audio('55')"></button>
<button class="stage1"
style="width: 415px; height: 290px; margin-top: 435px; margin-left: 830px; background: transparent;"
onclick="audio('66')"></button>

</div>
</div>



Javascript:





   <script>
function second_function()
{




$.mobile.changePage('#two',{transition: 'slide',allowSamePageTransition: true});



 }


 function home_function()
{

$.mobile.changePage('#one',{transition: 'slide',reverse : true,allowSamePageTransition: true});



 }

 function second_function()
 {


$.mobile.changePage('#three',{transition: 'slide',allowSamePageTransition: true});

 }


</script>
```

Comment: I suppose you use jQuery Mobile, don't you?

Comment: yes i used jquery mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page structure is wrong.
Have a look at the "page anatomy" provided by the developers: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

2)It's not necessary to switch pages manually (`$.mobile.changePage()`).
Better use:

```
<a href="#page1" data-transition="flip">Foo</a>
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

Comment: Actually you are saying right but i have some limitations that there should be no header and no footer